# how can i keep popover alive while the popover is being hovered for (ngx-bootstrap)?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

how can I keep popover alive while the popover is being hovered for ngx-bootstrap/popover angular 2 package?

thanks for your replies

Comment: can you be more specific? shouldn't the popover be always shown while the item is hovered? can you show your code?

Comment: @ShinDarth hi my friend, 
this is an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/x2VMhh?p=preview

Comment: ok but what are you trying to accomplish? you asked "how can I keep popover alive while the popover is being hovered" and from your example it is already the case

Comment: @ShinDarth this example not working with ngx-bootstrap. i want to use ngx-bootstrap for keeping alive the popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might refer to [ngx-popover](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover)

```
    import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';// or import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [PopoverModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

**Template**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        popover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Live demo
</button>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-popover-basic',
  templateUrl: './basic.html'
})
export class DemoPopoverBasicComponent {}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Tooltip** is what you need:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip

```
<button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    type="button"
    tooltip="This text will be shown when the button is hovered">
    Hover me!
</button>
```

Comment: I want to show an html content on popover! The tooltip is not suitable for this purpose

Comment: also… the popover is closing too, when user tries to hover the tooltip